# Unexpected version of python3 invoked

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, ubuntu

On ubuntu I have python 3.5.2 at /usr/bin. And then I installed python 3.6.3 installed at /usr/local/bin.

In my $PATH, /usr/local/bin is before /usr/bin, so when I run "python -V", it should be 3.6.3 from /usr/local/bin (this is consistent with the output of "which").

However, what happens is that when I run "python -V", 3.5.2 from /usr/bin is invoked.

See below.

```
me@myserver:/usr/local/bin$ /usr/local/bin/python3 -V
Python 3.6.3
me@myserver:/usr/local/bin$ /usr/bin/python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
me@myserver:/usr/local/bin$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
me@myserver:/usr/local/bin$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared after a restart.